# Flutter: After enabling web support... iOS simulators disappeared

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

I have followed below url and enabled web for my flutter application.

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

```
flutter channel master
flutter config --enable-web
flutter create .
flutter run -d chrome
flutter build web
```

Everything went well and I am able to launch my application on Web. However, after enabling web my ios simulators not appearing in devices list.

```
flutter devices

2 connected devices:
Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3955.4 dev
Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
```

Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Here's my environment:

```
flutter --version

Flutter 1.10.15-pre.424 • channel master •
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 289b458 (21 hours ago) • 2019-11-06 02:51:17 -0500
Engine • revision 9726b4cb99
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
```

```
dart --version

Dart VM version: 2.6.0 (Thu Oct 24 17:52:22 2019 +0200) on "macos_x64"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44326 I have updated my xcode from 9.4.1 to 11.2. Now the issue is fixed and I am able to see all devices.